# Argument not optional error when returning dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, object, dictionary, arguments

I have the following code in VBA and i'm trying to capture the dictionary object returned by the first function Parents in the line that says "Set Parents = Parents()" but I keep getting the Argument not optional error.

Everyone on the internet says it's usually because the Set keyword is missing but in this case it isn't. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
Public Function Parents() As Dictionary
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim DataLine As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Set Parents = New Dictionary


    FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\parents.txt"

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FilePath For Input As #FileNum

    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
        Parents.Add DataLine, 1
    Wend
End Function

Public Sub ComputeChanges()
    .
    .
    Dim Parents As Dictionary, Adjustments As Dictionary, inner As Dictionary, Changes As Dictionary
    Set Parents = Parents()
    .
    .
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your function to a sub and passing the pre-declared dictionary object in as a parameter.

```
Public Sub constructParents(dPRNTs As Dictionary)

    dPRNTs.RemoveAll
    dPRNTs.CompareMode = TextCompare

    dPRNTs.Add Key:="Joe & Jill", Item:=100
    dPRNTs.Add Key:="Sam & Sally", Item:=200
    dPRNTs.Add Key:="Dave & Debbie", Item:=300
    dPRNTs.Add Key:="Bob & Jane", Item:=400
    Debug.Print dPRNTs.Count

End Sub

Public Sub ComputeChanges()

    Dim dParents As New Dictionary, vKEY As Variant

    constructParents dParents
    'optionally use this if it makes more sense
    'Call constructParents(dParents)

    For Each vKEY In dParents
        Debug.Print "key: " & vKEY & ", item: " & dParents.Item(vKEY)
    Next vKEY

End Sub
```

I've simplified your code in order that I did not have to completely duplicate the environment but I hope you can transcribe this method for your own purposes.